# AngularJS, expressJS passportJS return user object after social auth

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, angularjs, express

This bugs me for two days and I cannot find good example on the internet for this.

I have two routes for facebook authentication using passport js, so I have like:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    'successRedirect': '/#/account',
    'failureRedirect': '/'
  })
);
```

Now I requested in this particular server through angularjs `$http.post`, like so:

```
angular.module('whimApp')
  .factory('AuthService', function ($http, API) {

    return {
      login: function() {
        return $http.get(API + 'auth/facebook')
          .then(function(res){
            Session.create(res.id, res.user.id);
            return res.user;
          });
      },
    };
  });
```

And I am getting this error:

```
 https://localhost:3000/auth/facebooknet::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I wonder if how would I be able to just do:

```
app.get('/auth/github/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'),
  // HERE is what i want to do
  // if successful login return user
  function(req,res,next) {
    res.json(req.user);
  }
);
```

Do you have any references there.

Comment: Have you checked This tutorial for facebook authentication?http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-facebook

Comment: yes.. it'll work if I will just go ahead and visit : auth/facebook, it will not work if i access it using `$http.get`

Comment: you need to redirect user to /auth/facebook which will redirect user to facebook, where user need to sign in and accept your application. so you can't do it with $http.get or any ajax request.

Comment: ah so authentication must be done like that, and not with some ajax request, I just need to store the auth token in the server and fetch it right?